# categorized barchart in bokeh python

Tags: python, bar-chart, bokeh

I am trying to plot 3 level category in bokeh python, but I am facing issue and my plot is not working, Could you give me a hand on this ?

below is my code :

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, FactorRange
from bokeh.io import show
p = figure(plot_height=250, title="Fruit Counts by Year")

#tp is my data as pandas DataFrame

x1=list(tp['SRN'])
x2=list(tp['SN'])
x3=list(tp['PN'])
counts = list(tp['VS.FEGE.RXMAXSPEED'])
x=[("SRN"+str(a1),"SN"+str(a2),"pN"+str(a3)) for a1,a2,a3 in zip(x1,x2,x3)]
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, counts=counts))
p =figure(x_range=FactorRange(*x),plot_height=250,title="title",toolbar_location=None, tools="")
p.vbar(x='x', top='counts', width=0.9,source=source)
show(p)
```

tp data is as below :

```
   SRN  SN  PN  VS.FEGE.RXMAXSPEED  VS.FEGE.TXMAXSPEED
0   0   18  0   1.794           0.307
1   0   18  1   1.896           0.307
2   0   19  0   131238.122      574793.502
3   0   19  1   31806.984       126149.078
4   0   20  0   4.968           0.307
```

I am not receiving any specific error, just plot is not shown. 
Also I want to know how "x_range=FactorRange(*x)" is working and is there any alernative way instead ?

Comment: I don't know why some persons are not going to help, they only could downvote. I tried and search alot, I could not find the reason why it is not working, and there is no 3 level categorized bar chart

Comment: if you could not solve it, atleast do not downvote please and let others help

Comment: Is there any output or error in the browsers JavaScript console?

Comment: When run your code with just the data above, it works fine. So I have to suspect there is an issue with your full data set. Can you make it available? If not, I can only speculate that perhaps it's such that duplicate factors are getting created, which would cause problems. The factors passed to `FactorRange` must be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, 
it is due to that x_range key argument is defined again in figure, if x_range is referenced later based on data, it will solve the issue :

```
p =figure(x_range=FactorRange(*x),plot_height=250,title="title",toolbar_location=e, tools="")

p.x_range.factors = x
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you have not imported Bokeh.Plotting which defines the figure.

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, FactorRange
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh import plotting

p = plotting.figure(plot_height=250, title="Fruit Counts by Year")
```

Call "figure" function like this whereever you are using it. It will resolve the "Figure not defined" error which is occurring in your case.

Comment: I included, i did not mentioned here, my problem is that "x_range=FactorRange(*x)" is not working properly